# Don't know how to handle exceptions Leaf.xNet

Tags: c#

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";
req.KeepAlive = true;
req.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
req.ConnectTimeout = 5000;
req.Cookies = null;
req.UseCookies = true;

string get = req.Get("https://grp02.id.rakuten.co.jp/rms/nid/logini?",null).ToString(); //Error
```

Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.CreateTcpConnection(String host, Int32 port)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.CreateConnection(Uri address)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.TryCreateConnectionOrUseExisting(Uri address, Uri previousAddress)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.Request(HttpMethod method, Uri address, HttpContent content)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.Raw(HttpMethod method, Uri address, HttpContent content)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.Raw(HttpMethod method, String address, HttpContent content)
Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest.Get(String address, RequestParams urlParams)

Exception tracked.
Don't know how to handle exceptions Leaf.xNet
I don't want to make exceptions.

Comment: "Exception tracked" - what do you mean? What exception is actually being thrown? Please edit your question to make it *much* clearer.

Comment: We looked at what lines actually happen

"string get = req.Get("https://grp02.id.rakuten.co.jp/rms/nid/logini?",null).ToString(); "

This is where it happened

Leaf.xNet.HttpRequest exceptions 
The exception occurs many times.

Comment: What exception though? You've shown a stack trace, but nothing about the exception type or the exception message. Again, please edit the question to be much clearer. At the moment, it basically says "Something's going wrong, how do I fix it?" That's not enough information.